# Wrong scaling in xyz coordinate systems

Tags: tikz-pgf

As stated in the Manual in section 10.2.1 "the default z-vector points to (-sqrt(2), -sqrt(2)).
But when I draw:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[axis/.style={thick,->}]
    \coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);
    \draw[axis] (O) -- +(1, 0, 0) node [right] {$X$};
    \draw[axis] (O) -- +(0, 1, 0) node [right] {$Y$};
    \draw[axis] (O) -- +(0, 0, 1) node [above] {$Z$};
    \draw[red, thick]   (O) -- +(-0.70710678, -0.70710678);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image: TikZ output]

As you can see: the red line is clearily longer than the z-axis, whereas it should be equal in length.
Can someone point me to the right direction?

During my investigations I found another strange behaviour:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red]          (-2cm,-2cm) grid (3,2cm);
    \coordinate         (O) at (0, 0, 0);
    \draw[blue]         (O) -- +(0, 1cm, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Yields two pages: the first one is empty, and the second one looks like:

[image: output]

This is the whole page, I didn't clip anything.

I am totally confused.

Comment: In my version of the manual, it says that the default z vector points to −3.85mm, −3.85mm, which seems correct.

Comment: Also from a response of Till Tantau to another bug in 3D library **I fixed this, but note that this library is not officially supported in any way...**

Comment: @percusse: I don't think Rico-E is using the 3D library. As I understand it, the `xyz` coordinate system is part of the main TikZ package (it's documented under "Specifying coordinates", not under "Libraries")

Comment: @Jake: please look at http://paws.wcu.edu/tsfoguel/tikzpgfmanual.pdf at page 83 in the middle of the page. Where do you get your info from? And why is it that strange length?

Comment: @all: can someone help me with the second strange behaviour where the blue line exceeds the grid by far.

Comment: @Rico-E: Wow, that's a *really* old manual (version 1.18 from 2007, the current one is 2.10). You can find it at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf (or simply type `texdoc pgf` on the command line to get the manual that matches your installed TikZ version).

Comment: @Rico-E: The second behaviour happens because the `1cm` in `(0,1cm,0)` is interpreted not as a length, but as a multiplier of the unit vector after converting `1cm` to `28.45pt`, so your blue line is 28.45cm long. This looks like a bug, or at least unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Jake Indeed, just an additional info about the view on 3D tools from TikZ development side. The empty page is also visible on writelatex though

Comment: @Jake: thank you. One last question for understanding: Is there a special explanation for the strange 3.85mm? Is it something like sin(22.5)?

Comment: @Rico-E: Sorry, I don't know why that value was chosen. `(3.54mm,3.54mm)` would correspond to a [cabinet projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_projection#Cabinet_projection) (angle of 45 degrees, foreshortening of 0.5). You can specify the `z` vector in your document using `z={(3.54mm,3.54mm)}`, if you want.

Comment: A trick: As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: @Tobi: that should be included in the format help pages. But this problem is solved, at least for me ;)

Comment: @Rico-E: Well, post your commend as question in meta ;-)

Comment: @ted: I did, but I can mark the anwser as solved after 24h...

Comment: @Jake: [Till does not know (or tell)](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/257/#569d) why that value was choosen either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All credit goes to Jake!

This answer is based on his comments:

The first problem was based on an old version of the manual which I used. In the [current manual](http://mirror.physik-pool.tu-berlin.de/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) they state, that the default z vector points to `(−3.85mm, −3.85mm)`, which is correct.

For the solution of my second problem, I'm citing Jake:

> The second behaviour happens because the `1cm` in `(0,1cm,0)` is interpreted not as a length, but as a multiplier of the unit vector after converting `1cm` to `28.45pt`, so your blue line is `28.45cm` long. This looks like a bug, or at least unexpected behaviour

Comment: I took the liberty to add the part about oblique projection from the comments explaining the whereabouts from the values, that looked like "god given" constants before.

Comment: @ted: I'm afraid your edit is wrong, and Jake is once more right. He stated:  I don't know why that value was chosen. (3.54mm,3.54mm) would correspond to a cabinet projection (angle of 45 degrees, foreshortening of 0.5). And that is totally correct: sin(225) = sin(45). And sin(45)*0.5 = 0.353 and not 0.385. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Rico-E you and Jake are right (apart from the sign on `sin(225)`). The values correspond to a scale of `.5444` rather than `.5`.  I have removed the edit.

Comment: @Rico-E: I added a [ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/257/), asking to either set this reasonably or to explain the value in the manual. The bug tracker looks really clena, I think we might get a new official release soon :p.